# Update multiple tables with multiple rows with trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, common-table-expression

I have these tables `Users, UserPackages, Packages, Refers`.

`Users` table has columns `UserRef_NO` (his own unique number), `RefNo` (if he registered using someones reference number) and `Refarning` (where he/she gets earning if someone registered using his refNo and bought a package and package status changed to 'True').

`UserPackages` table has columns `U_ID` (foreign key to `Users`), P_ID (foreign key to `Packages`), `PackageStatus` (true if bought false if not), `BuyDate` (generated as soon as `PackageStatus` changes to true), `ExpiryDate` (calculated from the join of `Packages` table and `BuyDate` where validity is total days of `Packages`)

`Packages` table has columns `Price`, `ReferComission` (in percentage), `Validity` (in days).

EDIT:- Third Edit this works fine for single row updates but fails for multi row updates saying subquery returned more then one value

```
alter TRIGGER [dbo].[HeavyTriggerTest] ON [dbo].[UserPackages]
   after update
   as

  update UP set
  BuyDate = GETDATE(), Expirydate = dateadd(dd, P.Validitiy, getdate()) 
from dbo.UserPackages UP
inner join Inserted I on I.P_ID = UP.P_ID and I.U_ID = UP.U_ID
inner join dbo.Packages P on P.PID = I.P_ID
where UP.PackageStatus = 'True';

  ;
 with firstCte(Name,UID,PName,Price,ReferComission,ReferredBy)
 as
 (
 select distinct Users.Name,Users.ID,Packages.PName,Packages.Price,Packages.ReferCommission,(select DISTINCT ID from Users
 where Users.UserRef_No=Refers.RefOf )
 from Users inner join UserPackages on UserPackages.U_ID=Users.ID
  inner join Packages on Packages.PID=UserPackages.P_ID
  inner join Refers on Users.Ref_No=Refers.RefOf  
  inner join Inserted I on I.U_ID = UserPackages.U_ID and I.P_ID = UserPackages.P_ID
 and UserPackages.PackageStatus='true' AND UserPackages.U_ID=i.U_ID 
 AND Refers.RefOf=(SELECT users.Ref_No where UserPackages. U_ID=i.U_ID)
 )

 update  Users set RefEarning+= Price*ReferComission/100 from firstCte where ID=ReferredBy ;
    

 update Users set Active='True' where ID=(select U_ID from inserted) and Active='False'
```

and here's the single update query which i tried to replace with above last two updates but it gives wrong results plus it also doesn't work for multiple row updates

```
 update Users set RefEarning+=(
 case when ID=firstCte.ReferredBy then firstCte.Price*ReferComission/100 else RefEarning end)
 ,Active=case when ID=(select U_ID from inserted) and Active='false'  then 'True' 
 when firstCte.ReferredBy=(select U_ID from inserted) then 'true' else Active end
  from  firstCte
```

Comment: Just join `Inserted` to your query. Or use in as your previous question.

Comment: People have already spent a lot of time trying to explain to you how this works. Inserted is essentially a table, use it as you would any other table. And google inserted table sql server and learn a bit more. If you keep getting people to write this code for you, you won't learn how it all works.

Comment: @DaleK i think i got the concept of Inserted Table the above query i posted is not the first one.i have created many other but only the above one works fine for single row updated all others don't work for all tables i.e few tables are update few are not.Joining with inserted table didn't work for the above case...the very first update query works fine i.e it changes package status in userpackages table but nothing else gets updated

Comment: I've just told you 2 techniques to use make it multi-line, either join it on, or use it as `IN` as per your previous question. So have a go at that and let us know when you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Your second query, first update, you need to join `Inserted` on as:

```
update UP set
  BuyDate = GETDATE(), Expirydate = dateadd(dd, P.Validitiy, getdate()) 
from dbo.UserPackages UP
inner join Inserted I on I.P_IP = UP_P_ID and I.U_ID = UP.U_ID
inner join dbo.Packages P on P.PID = I.P_ID
where UP.PackageStatus = 'True';
```

Note the table aliases which I recommended to you in your last question - they make it much easier to read through a query.

Also note its best practice to schema qualify your tables.

Second query, second update:

```
with firstCte ([Name], [UID], PName, Price, ReferComission, ReferredBy)
as
(
  select U.[Name], U.ID, P.PName, P.Price, P.ReferCommission
    , max(U.ID) over () as referedby 
  from Users U
  inner join UserPackages UP on UP.U_ID = U.ID
  inner join Packages P on P.PID = UP.P_ID
  inner join Refers R on R.RefOf = U.Ref_No 
  inner join Inserted I on I.U_ID = UP.U_ID and I.P_ID = UP.P_ID
  where UP.PackageStatus='true' 
)
update U set
  Active = 'True'
  , RefEarning += Price*ReferComission/100
from Users U
inner join firstCte on ReferredBy = U.id
where Active = 'False';
```

Note the window function `max` to avoid repeating the query in a sub-query.

Note joining the CTE to the Users table to perform the update.

Comment: same thing only the first row is getting updated..this is the test update query UPDATE dbo.UserPackages SET PackageStatus = 'True' WHERE U_ID IN (9,2) and P_ID in (1,3);

Comment: @Jazz then your actual logic (which I just copied) must be wrong. This shows how to do a *proper* multi-row update, but you have to verify that your joins and logic etc work correctly as we don't have enough information to do so.

Comment: You can simulate a trigger by creating a temp table #Inserted and putting some rows in it and then test the data that your queries return. Or as a first step you can slap a whole load of select statements in your trigger and call your update from SSMS. This is now a debug job, you have to investigate and determine at what point its not giving you the results you expect.

Comment: the above query you posted as well the one i posted works fine when i update any single row but fails for the update query i posted above in comments

Comment: As I said, there is something wrong with the logic... you need to debug it.

Comment: won't it fail  for single row too if logic wasn't right?or do i need to create a new logic for multiple updates?

Comment: @Jazz I don't know - you are the only person who has that level of knowledge about your system. Instead of guessing... debug it! :)

Comment: @Jazz add each select without the update in the trigger and see what happens, you'll soon see whats going wrong.

Comment: update U set
  Active = 'True'
  , RefEarning += Price*ReferComission/100
from Users U
inner join firstCte on ReferredBy = U.id
where Active = 'False'; HERE'S THE issue you cannot update two rows at the same time so i need to do two updates i.e one for each user as one's need to be set to true and the others need to add ReferComisision.

Comment: you were right query was not working manually to but even after setting that now i can't update multiple rows at all with test update query..but manually for single row its working fine

Comment: Of course you can update 2 rows at the same time... thats the whole premise of set based logic. Unless you have duplicates users?

Comment: duplicate users as in?each user has unique ID so if they are referred by ID then there won't be any duplicates.how would you devise a logic to update two users with different ID's and assign ReferComission to one user and Active status to True to the other one?

Comment: use `case` expressions as I showed you in your previous question.